# Display flag emojis in Google Sheets using Windows 10

Tags: google-sheets, emoji, windows-10

When I write a flag emoji like  into a Google Sheets cell it displays as text and not as a flag when I am using Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge in Windows 10. Is there a way to display it as a flag with this setup?

Here is a sample spreadsheet which replicates the issue: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q9F237ay3IMYh-qULXSpQUx4-0_cPj-xoQWeQ2_-ooE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: When I copy and paste  to a Google Sheet, the flag displays in the cell just fine. Tested on Safari on macOS. Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet where the issue can be reproduced. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: @doubleunary thank you for the input. I have added more information about my set-up and a sample spreadsheet.

Comment: I see the flags and country names in cells `B10:F10` just fine, and the flags also show fine in the X axis labels in `Chart1`. It is unlikely that the issue is with Google Sheets. Try with another browser, and check your system for broken fonts and the like to identify what the problem is.

Comment: @doubleunary have you tried it in Google Chrome on Windows 10?

Comment: I have the same issue in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue in your sample spreadsheet. Check your system for broken fonts and the like.